# Call javascript function using php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the below code to call the javascript function from php script. Its not working while am adding the php variable in javascript($msg). Please help me to do this.

```
if ( isset($_GET['Error'])) {
    $msg =$_GET["Error"];
    echo '<script type="script.php">validate("Error",$msg);</script>';
}
```

Comment: `<script type="script.php">` isn't a valid value for the [`type` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp).  Change `script.php`

Comment: echo '<script type="script.php">validate("Error",$msg);</script>' can't call a php script.

It should read something like <script >validate("Error",$msg);</script>  but I'd have to know what the validate function does to be sure

anyway, you should leave the type attr off.  it's assumed now, but if you had to it's type="text/javascript"

Comment: <script >validate("Error",$msg);</script> not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the `$msg` or it will be syntax error in javascript.
And the `type` is non sense.

Since the msg is from the `$_GET`, don't forget the escape it.

```
if ( isset($_GET['Error'])) {
    $msg =$_GET["Error"];
    echo '<script>validate("Error", "'.htmlspecialchars($msg).'");</script>';
}
```

Comment: not good enough, though. by default it'll let `'` go through unencoded and STILL break the JS syntax. `json_encode(htmlspecialchars(...))` would do the trick.

Comment: @MarcB Even the `'` is quoted by `"`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an inline script, this should work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function testMe(x){
                alert(x);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<?php
    $phpVar = 'I am a PHP variable';

    echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:testMe('" . $phpVar . "');\">Click Me</a>";
?>
</body>
<html>
```